# Using exec command in puppet to create alias in Linux

Tags: puppet

Let's say I want to create alias for some command (for example ls command)

So far I've done:

```
class alias{
        exec { "alias1":
        command => "alias aliasname='ls'",
        user => root,
}
}
```

I added these lines to site.pp:

Exec { path => "/usr/bin"}

include alias

It says "Could not find command 'alias'". So I'm not sure why it doesn't work. Am I doing this totally wrong? Or is there any other way to make such alias ?And yes, I'm really new at this :)

Answer (score 2):

Alias is a shell builtin and does not live in PATH. An alias is active for the current session only, so even if your command worked it would only set the alias for the executed shell and then exit (and thus unset the alias again). The way you persist aliases is by writing them to a file that the shell reads in on startup. 
You should rather use a file/template or `file_line` from the puppet stdlib.

/etc/profile.d/ can be a good place to put something if you want to make the aliases global (available for everyone). If not *.bashrc* works well enough (though there is a convention of using a separate file *.alias* / *.bash_alias* ).

Answer (score 1):

it is wrong. require add alias definition to ~/.bashrc or /etc/profile.d/youname.sh
And alias is command for bash so require call command => "bash -c\"alias aliasname='ls'\"",